# Unable to make link in Wikipedia Hebrew

Tags: wikipedia

Please take a look at [this](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%A9:Weitzhandler/Interwiki_links_sandbox) Wikipedia sandbox source-code, there are two English words I'm trying to link to Wikipedia in English, but it freaks out, what am I doing wrong?

Here's the source-code of what I'm trying to achieve:

> ==After== עריפה הייתה גם השיטה בדרגה הגבוהה ביותר של
>   ענישה. אחת הדרכים הברוטליות ביותר לעריפה הייתה שיטת הסמוראים, כפי
>   שנהגו במקרהו של אישידה מיטסונרי (石田 三成 [[en:Ishida Mitsunari|Ishida
>   Mitsunari]]

Comment: Please _do not_ use URL shorteners here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you use produce an interwiki link that show up in the sidebar. what you need is to put a colon in front of the language code i.e. `[[:en:Ishida Mitsunari|Ishida Mitsunari]]`.

By the way, usually links to other language versions should not be used in the text like that, check your local policy if that is okay.